# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError send JSON Object in Android

Tags: android, json

I'm trying send a large video to PHP server from App Android, but I can't because always It's reports java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

I try to use, Apache components and HttpURLConnection but I can't send it...

I read a lot of similar questions but I can't do that.

**my code**

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>
    {
        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground (String... params)
        {
            String datos = value.getText().toString();
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpClient = getNewHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("My url");

try
            {

String youFilePathVideo = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/project/video.mp4";

                File file = new File(youFilePathVideo);
                byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                dis.readFully(fileData);
                dis.close();

                strBaseVideo=Base64.encodeToString(fileData, 0);

                JSONObject video = new JSONObject();
                try
                {
                    video.put("video.mp4", strBaseVideo);



                } catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

                jsonArray.put(video);

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("video", video.toString()));

 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

                responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Please, I need help, thanks.

Comment: do not encode, Please send the file only use apache library for multipart upload

Comment: obviously file is too big to load it to memory, you have to use some streaming API ... so: first, do not use base64 for sending the file ... send it as plain binary - of course you have to change the server side, too

Comment: I going to try @sunil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not the JSON string. It is more likely the video file being very large and you are loading it into the memory:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
dis.readFully(fileData);
dis.close();
```

Why do you need these 3 lines?

Comment: mmm maybe you have the reason, then delete that 3 lines?